# Get First nonrecurring element in a list using scala

Tags: scala

Getting an compilation error - forward reference extends over definition of value lst:

```
    val lt = List(1,2,3,3,2,4,5,1,5,7,8,7) 
    var cond = false 
    do 
    { 
        var cond = if (lt.tail contains lt.head) true else false 
        if (cond == true) { 
           val lst : List[Int]= lt.filter(_!=lt.head)
           val lt = lst
        }
        else { 
          println(lt.head)
        }
    }
    while(cond == false)
```

Comment: `cond` is not in scope.

Comment: You are defining variable `lt ` two times one outside the loop then again inside the loop.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, I defined those variables incorrectly!. Solution produced the expected result after I corrected it.

Comment: var lt = List(1,2,3,3,2,4,5,1,5,7,8,7,4)
  var cond = false
  do 
  {
    cond = if (lt.tail contains lt.head) true else false
    if (cond == true) {
      var lst : List[Int]= lt.filter(_!=lt.head)
      lt = lst
    }
    else { 
      println(lt.head)
    }
  }
  while(cond!=false)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement "Get first" using `find` and you can implement "non-recurring" using `count == 1` so the code is

```
lt.find(x => lt.count(_ == x) == 1)
```

This will return an `Option[Int]` that can be unpicked in the usual way.

This algorithm is clear but not efficient, so for a very long list you might want to pre-compute the count, or use a recursive function to implement your original algorithm. This would be less clear but more efficient, so avoid it unless you can prove that the inefficiency is causing a problem.

#### Update

Here is an example of pre-computing the count for each value. This is potentially faster for long lists because `Map` operations are typically O(log n) so the function is O(n log n) rather than O(n<sup>2</sup>) for the previous version.

```
def firstUniq[A](in: Seq[A]): Option[A] = {
  val m = mutable.Map.empty[A, Int]

  for (elem <- in) {
    m.update(elem, m.getOrElseUpdate(elem, 0) + 1)
  }

  val singles = m.filter(_._2 == 1)

  in.find(singles.contains)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## first non recurring element in whole list

> > Get First nonrecurring element in a list using scala

You can use `filter` and `count` as

```
val firstNonRecurrringValue = lt.filter(x => lt.count(_ == x) == 1)(0)
```

so `firstNonRecurrringValue` is `4`

## first non recurring element in the list after the element

But looking at your `do while` code, **it seems that you are trying to print the first element that is not recurring after it**. For that following code should work

```
val firstNonRecurringValue = lt.zipWithIndex.filter(x => lt.drop(x._2).count(_ == x._1) == 1)(0)._1
```

Now `firstNonRecurringValue` should be `3`